# Cannot change certain skype appearance features Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype

I have been trying to modify my skype appearance using `qtconfig`, mostly successful, however I cannot figure out how to change the colour of certain fields:
Here is the Image[skype-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kCPD.png) to look for?

Dark-grey top field with call button on it and bottom-left "call phones" field, plus the small field just above input field. It's a bit of an eyesore, I wonder if there is any way to change that?